# How to evaluate TCL callbacks one by one?

Tags: events, callback, tcl, stdin

Suppose some callback is registered for `stdin`.

```
fileevent stdin readable thatCallback
```

This means that during the execution of the [`update`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/update.htm) command it will evaluate `thatCallback` time after time while there is input available at `stdin`.

How can I make `thatCallback` to be evaluated only once during each call of [`update`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/update.htm)?

Comment: Your probably doing it wrong. There are nearly no good usecases for the update command. You could do what you want by simply removing the fileevent handler inside the callback and resetting it right after you called update, but it smells like the wrong problem to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each use of `update`, any particular event handler will be executed only once. That's because what `update` does is to check for which event handlers are runnable (and which events are actually queued) and then executes all the ready ones, once. It doesn't wait for further events to happen.

Now, the `fileevent` will still be registered so that the next time the event loop is entered it will possibly be runnable again. If you want a once-only `fileevent`, de-register the handler while it is running. For example:

```
fileevent stdin readable thatCallback
proc thatCallback {} {
    # First, de-register ourselves so we're a one-shot
    fileevent stdin readable {}
    # Now do the rest of it here...
}
```

Comment: But in this case the next calls of `update` will not call `tahtCallback`, right?

Comment: @Vahagn: Right, because there won't be anything registered to be called.